# How to fix is.data.frame(x) : object '' not found error when using pad

Tags: r

I've been using some code to fill in gaps in time series data with a simple pipe operation using both `pad` and `fill_by_value`. It was working perfectly for me for months, but today it decided to stop working and provide me with `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'y' not found`.

There are many questions asking to resolve this same error. Some of the solutions include putting brackets around the function producing the error (in this case `fill_by_value`), running `undebug` on the function (doesn't apply to me because none of my functions are in debug mode), and putting .$ in front of the object that isn't being found. None of these solutions have worked for me.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do (I found it in the examples section of the `pad` function description, which doesn't work either by the way):

```
library(padr); library(dplyr) # for the pipe operator
month <- seq(as.Date('2016-04-01'), as.Date('2017-04-01'),
             by = 'month')[c(1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13)]
month_df <- data.frame(month = month, y = runif(length(month), 10, 20))

# fill all y with 0
month_df %>% pad %>% fill_by_value(y)
```

This produces the error `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'y' not found` when it should transform the data from this:

```
       month        y
1 2016-04-01 19.75770
2 2016-07-01 10.90725
3 2016-08-01 12.68625
4 2016-10-01 12.78528
5 2016-12-01 12.00717
6 2017-01-01 19.70017
7 2017-04-01 14.06676
```

to this:

```
        month        y
1  2016-04-01 19.75770
2  2016-05-01        0
3  2016-06-01        0
4  2016-07-01 10.90725
5  2016-08-01 12.68625
6  2016-09-01        0
7  2016-10-01 12.78528
8  2016-11-01        0
9  2016-12-01 12.00717
10 2017-01-01 19.70017
11 2017-02-01        0
12 2017-03-01        0
13 2017-04-01 14.06676
```

Perhaps I am just ignorant to the ways of R, but I can't understand why this simple line of code stopped working for me.

Comment: The code works fine for me, I can't replicate the error. Try rerunning from a fresh session

Comment: Okay I did that, and I think I figured out why it's happening. I'm using the `EcoHydRology` package in my project, and this "masks" the pipe operator from `dplyr` when it's loaded. So if I run the code without `EcoHydRology` it works fine, but when I add `EcoHydRology` it produces the error. Any ideas as to how to fix that?

Comment: Try loading the `EcoHydRology` library before `dplyr`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the same thing happens.

Comment: There is no try, only do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of loading of libraries.

```
Restarting R session...

> library(padr)
> library(EcoHydRology)
Loading required package: operators

Attaching package: ‘operators’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    options, strrep

Loading required package: topmodel
Loading required package: DEoptim
Loading required package: parallel

DEoptim package
Differential Evolution algorithm in R
Authors: D. Ardia, K. Mullen, B. Peterson and J. Ulrich

Loading required package: XML
> library(dplyr) # for the pipe operator

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:operators’:

    %>%

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> month <- seq(as.Date('2016-04-01'), as.Date('2017-04-01'),
+              by = 'month')[c(1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13)]
> month_df <- data.frame(month = month, y = runif(length(month), 10, 20))
> # fill all y with 0
> month_df %>% pad %>% fill_by_value(y)
pad applied on the interval: month
        month        y
1  2016-04-01 19.88309
2  2016-05-01  0.00000
3  2016-06-01  0.00000
4  2016-07-01 17.46558
5  2016-08-01 10.34364
6  2016-09-01  0.00000
7  2016-10-01 13.82603
8  2016-11-01  0.00000
9  2016-12-01 17.36399
10 2017-01-01 19.55054
11 2017-02-01  0.00000
12 2017-03-01  0.00000
13 2017-04-01 15.62318
```

Comment: Alright this worked. Seems that putting `padr` first was the key.